# Objective-C memory leak, memory management question

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I am new to Objective C and believe I have a memory leak situation in this function, but I am not sure when to delete/release the objects.

Since I store the `recipeObject` into my View, I free it in the `dealloc` of the view, but I am not sure about the view?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RecipeObject * recipeObject = (RecipeObject *)[maRecipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    RecipeView * recipeView = [[RecipeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeView" bundle:nil];
    [recipeView setRecipeObject:RecipeObject];  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipeView animated:YES];
}
```

Can someone show me an example of what to do, or explain it?

Comment: Please provide useful headlines!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first rule to remember when you're dealing with memory management in Objective-C is that you're responsible for anything that you (1) allocate (using `alloc`), (2) new up (using `new`), (3) copy (using `copy`), or (4) retain (using `retain`). In those four cases, you must explicitly `release` (or `autorelease`) those references.

In your example, since you allocated recipeView, you must release it once it's added to the navigation controller.

```
RecipeView * recipeView = [[RecipeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipeView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:recipeView animated:YES];
[recipeView release];
```

If you don't do this, you'll leak recipeView since it goes out of scope once the method exits and you will no longer have a way to access the allocated space on the heap.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So do I always release the object immediately after I do 1, 2 or 3?  Or are there case where I would do the release at a later time?  I think the answer is yes... but in any case, it does make sense and I thank you for the help?

Comment: Also, what about if I do this in a function and return content?  Do I still release it before the return, or should do I release it later? NSMutableArray * content = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: You should release it when you're done with it. There's reason to hold onto allocated memory if you don't need it. There'll be cases where you'll be done with it right away and others where you'll need to hold onto it for a while. This will become clearer as you gain more experience.

Comment: If you're returning an object that you allocated in the method, then you should autorelease it. return [content autorelease]. It'll get added to the autorelease pool and released at the appropriate time.

Comment: Don't forget that you are also responsible for anything you specifically `retain`, in addition to `alloc`, `copy`, and `new`.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I had that in an earlier revision of my answer but inadvertently edited it out while cleaning up. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

You must release `recipeView` after the `pushViewController`.
When pushing it a retain is done, then when popping a release is done.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the last line of the code

```
[recipeView release];
```